# Outputting query results

Tags: database, wpdb

I am trying to make plugin, and i followed [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), i am not a OOP literate, hence i a blank. I tried to run this query 
`$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT question FROM wp_quiz" );`

while i tried to echo $myrows but it didn't gave me anything, so i tried to `print_r($myrows)`, which gave me my output with the following prepend text

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [question] => What is the flag color of Pakistan ) )

How can i echo out a proper column from the table, because i just seemed to start.? Do i need to do crash course on OOP before getting into this? What should i know.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, wordpress get_results return a numerically array of objects, so to use echo to print your data yo should do something like;

```
foreach($myrows as $line){
  echo $line->question;
}
```

Comment: where do i read this stuff? As i need to insert data later too, and do complex queries on db. I am a starter.

Comment: You can see the output_type for get_results on codex, on the link you put on your post.

Comment: so i need to learn OOP first?

Comment: The wordpress core is oop programmed so when you call to $wpdb->get_results you are calling method from class... but you can do a lot od stuff just knowing the basics.

Comment: "The wordpress core is oop programmed" not completely true.

Comment: it's true, wordpress is not fully oop developed but lots of its apis are written as classes.